# ImmutableJS: Merging two Lists by values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux, immutable.js

I have two [Immutable.JS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) lists:

```
const numbers = fromJS([2]);
const moreNumbers = fromJS([1, 2]);
```

How can I merge these ***by value*** and ***preserving order*** to produce the following list?

```
[2, 1]
```

The idea is to replicate [`union`](https://lodash.com/docs/#union) from the Lodash.

This function *creates an array of unique values, in order, from all given arrays using SameValueZero for equality comparisons.*

Comment: with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set/union) with `union()`

```
import { Set } from 'immutable'
const s1 = Set([2])
const s2 = Set([1,2])
const s3 = s1.union(s2)
console.log(s3.toArray()) // [2,1]
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/fabowitoju/edit?js,console)

Comment: Can you expand with an example?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/fa06db9b2bdb1405971121528163390284701639/__tests__/Set.ts#L120-L125

Comment: My question has been expanded :-)

Comment: What part of Set does not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Normally a good answer include concise answers with examples not links to docs, they are also great to have as well.

Comment: Added example! :)